# Is it possible to overload a thin conductive object with electrons?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, electrons, voltage, electronic-band-theory

A parallel-plate capacitor is a very simple device.  To make one, you can take two metal plates, separate them with a dielectric material, and voilà!  You have a capacitor.

Given a dielectric permittivity $\varepsilon$, a plate area $A$, a voltage $V$, and a dielectric thickness $d$, the amount of charge on each plate is given by $Q = \varepsilon A V/d$.  For example, suppose that $\varepsilon = 10^5 \cdot \varepsilon_0; A = 1 \,\mathrm{cm^2}; V = 10^4 \,\mathrm{V}; d = 1 \,\mathrm{mm}$.  (These are high values, but not obviously out of reach for giant-dielectric-constant materials like CCTO.)  Then $Q = 8.85 \times 10^{-4} \,\mathrm{C} = 5.5 \times 10^{15} q_e$, where $q_e$ is the electron charge.

Now, classically speaking, there is no restriction on the thickness of the plates, as long as they are conductive.  Therefore, let's try to make the plates as thin as we possibly can.  (Of course, extremely thin plates have high resistance; to avoid overheating, we will be careful to charge the capacitor very slowly.)  In fact, let's make the plates out of graphene.  Graphene is a two-dimensional material with an atom density of [$3.9\times 10^{15} \,\mathrm{cm^{-2}}$](http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/%7Ephys123B/w2015/pdf_CoursGraphene2008.pdf)... which means that one of our capacitor plates has more electrons than atoms, while the other plate has lost all of its free electrons.

That sounds impossible, but what exactly would go wrong if you built this device in real life and tried to charge it to 10,000 V?  Would you see a large voltage drop at the edges of the plates, followed eventually by electrical breakdown?  Would something else fail, e.g. would electrons start to leak into/out of the dielectric?